# Send HTTP request to site in docker container

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I am new to docker containers and I have written a python script that takes in data from a port that will then be sent to a website.  Before it gets sent to the site, I have to get a key from a different site to access it.  The script runs and is able to do this when I run it locally, but when I attempt to run it in the docker container it is never able to connect when using requests to send HTTP post requests.  The following is the error I get when trying to run the docker image:

```
File "python_script.py", line 41, in <module>
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=creds, allow_redirects=False, auth=("some_username", "some_password"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

Here is the code where this error occurs:

```
token_url = "https://some_website"
creds = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=creds, allow_redirects=False, auth=("some_username", "some_password"))
json_response = json.loads(access_token_response.text)
jwt = json_response['access_token']
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["python", "python_script.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python2"]
```

I built the docker image with:

```
sudo docker build --network=host -t name_of_docker_directory .
```

And am running it with:

```
sudo docker run -it name_of_docker_directory python_script.py
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot this by looking online.  I have seen some information about needing to expose ports or connect them to the docker image but I am not sure how to find the right ports so that I can get the access key and then send data to the site.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add your Dockerfile and run configuration

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.  Is the "different site" running inside another Docker container, for instance?